# import from {in,out}side of a packages

Tags: python, import

I have a project I build on a library I'm building in parallel. The structure is the following :

```
project/
  main.py
  MyLibrary/
    __init__.py --> empty
      Module1.py --> contain the class Class1
      Module2.py --> contain the class Class2
      Module3.py --> contain the class Class3
      ...
```

I need to import the class Class2 into Class1.py, if I do

```
from Module1 import Class1
```

it's ok. But when in project/main.py I do

```
from MyLibrary import Module1
```

I got ImportError: No module name Module1

I could solve the issue by replacing:

```
from Module1 import Class1
```

by

```
from .Module1 import Class1
```

But then I'm not able any more to run Module1.py direcly (Python complain that I'm trying to do a relative impact on a non package...). And I need that to run test.

How I could I have import that work in both case ?

Thank for your attention !

edit: the first described solution seems to work on my linux desktop but not on my windows Xp powerred laptop. It's weird...

Comment: With these names it's hard do say if you're trying to import modules (best practice) or classes from inside modules (not so hot), and what you're getting. Plus, the use of "Class1" everywhere except a fleeting mention of Class2 is headache-inducing. Please do some sensible renaming (e.g. Mod1, Mod2 for the modules!-) and clarify which ones are you trying to import, from where, with what on sys.path, and what current directory.

Comment: You are writing you wanted to "import the class Class2 into Class1.py". But then you try to achieve that with `from Class1 import Class1`. This does not make sense.

Comment: My bad I changed module name for better clarity (I hope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing (where imports work normally on one machine and not another) often happens because you've got multiple packages named MyLibrary on one system and your PYTHONPATH doesn't list '.' first.

To test if this is the problem, in the project directory, run Python and do

```
>>> import MyLibrary
>>> print MyLibrary
```

and see if the path to MyLibrary matches your expectations.  If it doesn't, tweak your PYTHONPATH and/or delete the outdated version of your package.

A common way to avoid this sort of problem is to use virtualenv to create an isolated Python environment.